# Inject mocks into class before constructor's logic comes on

Tags: java, android, testing, mocking, mockito

Imagine, we have a class, in which a lot of logic is being executed inside a constructor.

**A question**: how to inject mocks in such class before constructor's logic gets executed?

**Additional info:**

This class is not written by me and I do not want to violate the existing interface in this class by changing its structure for testability reasons. Worth mentioning, that it is a [ViewModel's](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) class instance and on its instantiation it runs an authentication check in RxJava2 flow, using this viewModel's fields to get needed Observables.

So, it is throwing NullPointerException even before @InjectMocks annotation comes in. If I try not to instantiate viewmodel in testing class viewmodel's field declaration, then run fails due to 'MockitoException', that is caused because of trying of Mockito itself to instantiate an object with intent to inject mocks in it after, but constructor already fails with NPE.

So, it is even possible to solve this without violation of 'do not change a class for test' rule?

Comment: Could you add an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can understand your problem better? Also I don't think that `'do not change a class for test' rule` is a good rule. If your code is hard to test you should probably refactor it to make it testable.

Comment: Beyond that : when you don't own that class - why do you want to test it? What happens when you find a bug? Then: if you are looking for a less generic answer - you should add a bit more of example code. Feel free to drop me a comment if you want to further look into this (next week then).

Comment: @GhostCat , I just had a task on my work to test a couple of existing ViewModels, preferable without using of reflection API (which was quite impossible). But I and my colleagues agreed, that constructor injection would be a much better solution either for testability and explicit classes' dependencies exposing (opposite to fields injection by turning to singleton application). Now classes are open for testing and all seems OK. Thanks again for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only *real* answer here: you are investing your time and energy in the wrong place.

You see:

> we have a class, in which a lot of logic is being executed inside a constructor

is an **anti pattern**. For once: because it makes *testing* your class so hard. You run exactly into such situations: meaningful resolving of your *dependencies* is close to impossible. If you find your code *hard to test*, then that is most often a direct consequence of *bad design*. So refactoring your code can not only make it testable, it also can improve its quality dramatically!

But your "solution" is to use mocking framework magic as band-aid. But that is the wrong approach: because you still can't easily instantiate your "objects under test". And that problem will manifest itself in all kinds of other symptoms over time.

In that sense: learn how to write testable code - for example by watching these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79).

If you really want/have to keep that class like it is - then rather look into using a **dependency injection** framework such as [guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted).

Comment: Again: this class is not written by me. Anyway, here is no really adequate solutions, so I am going to mark this as a correct answer.